# Gambler's Ruin With a Pay Schedule

Tags: combinatorics, gambling

I am curious about how to calculate the expected number of games until a gambler with $B$ dollars gets to $M>B$ dollars, or gets ruined.

I am also curious how to calculate the probability of ruin. I have seen this calculation done with a player who can win 1 dollar or lose 1 dollar. Is there a way to do this when there are $N$ different win amounts, with $N$ different probabilities? I have seen a reference to [Guy Katriel's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4203.pdf), but it looks at favorable games. I am looking for a derivation for unfavorable games.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read: How to gamble if you must inequalities for stochastic processes by Dubbins & Savage

Comment: Do you mean that there are $N$ different games that the player can choose from, each with a different winning probability (and also with different payouts), or do you mean that basically the game consists of repeatedly rolling a biased $N$ sided die and then getting whatever payout is rolled?

Comment: Like video poker (if you've played). Some hands pay more than others, and occur with different probabilities. I think that's what you were saying with the N sided die bit.

Answer (score 0):

The paper
G. Katriel, Gambler’s Ruin: The Duration of Play, Stochastic Models 30 (2014), 251-271
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/15326349.2014.902317
considers a general unfavorable game, and gives a formula for the expected to 
ruin. However the case where there is also an upper bound B is not treated there.
When you have an upper bound, the problem is a finite Markov chain, so at least
computationally it can be treated by standard Markov chain techniques.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.